# How to pass a parameter from Vb.net combobox to reportviewer?

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Studio express 2013 and coding in VB.NET.
I have created a report in Reportbuilder 3.0 with a parameter (`Plaasnaamprm`).
I would like to pass a parameter to the report via a `combobox` on my windows application form.

When I run my apllication, I get the following error message on the reportviewer :

> "The 'Plaasnaamprm' parameter is missing a value".

I have tried the approach described here : [How can I pass parameter to Reportviewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060213/how-can-i-pass-parameter-to-reportviewer)

Here is my code :

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms


Public Class Form2

  Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'SkeduleringDatabasisDataSet.Blokke' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.BlokkeTableAdapter.Fill(Me.SkeduleringDatabasisDataSet.Blokke)
    Dim Plaasnaamprm(0) As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter

    Dim cn As New SqlConnection
    cn.ConnectionString = My.Settings.SkeduleringDatabasisConnectionString
    cn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sql As New SqlCommand("select * from blokke order by plaasnaam ", cn)
    Dim bs As New BindingSource
    Dim blokke As New DataTable
    Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", blokke)

    da.SelectCommand = sql
    da.Fill(blokke)
    bs.DataSource = blokke

    Plaasnaamprm(0) = New     Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Plaasnaamprm,combobox1.selectedvaue")

    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\Users\Administrator   \Desktop\SKED PROGRAM\Skedulering_Mei_2015\Skeduleer2\Verslae\parskaartjies9.rdlc"
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(Plaasnaamprm)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
    ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

  End Sub
End Class
```

I am stumped, so any help would be much appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not passing the required value for the parameter.

try changing this:

```
Plaasnaamprm(0) = New     Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Plaasnaamprm,combobox1.selectedvaue")
```

to

```
Plaasnaamprm(0) = New     Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("Plaasnaamprm",combobox1.selectedvalue)
```